# Tem como pegar o tempo que se passou?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Eu to desenvolvendo um joguinho no qual o usuário vai ganhar **200 de dinheiro** por minuto.

Eu tenho um script simples de comparação de tempo pronto, que salva o **tempo atual(+ 1 minuto)** no banco de dados e compara com o verdadeiro tempo atual.

```
$_SESSION['waterhour'] = new DateTime();
    echo $_SESSION['waterhour']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<BR>";
    $_SESSION['waterhourplus'] = new DateTime('+1 minutes');
     echo $_SESSION['waterhourplus']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Quando a hora do banco de dados **for igual a atual** irá realizar um update no dinheiro do usuário.

```
if ($_SESSION['timewater'] == $_SESSION['waterhour']) {
            $objUpWater = new Resources();
            $objUpWater->WaterUpdate();
        }
```

Até ai tudo bem, tudo funciona corretamente se o usuário ficar atualizando a página de **1 em 1 minuto**, o que eu queria saber é como pegar o tempo que se passou caso o usuário não atualize a página a cada 1 minuto.

Por exemplo, quando o usuário ficar mais de 5 minutos sem atualizar a página o tempo ficará (*-4 minutos)*.

Tem como pegar esses *-4 minutos* ? Já que os minutos serão usados como a quantidade de vezes que o usuário irá ganhar o dinheiro.

obs: Eu não queria usar cron job, não iria funcionar corretamente já que cada usuário teria segundos de diferenças na hora de ganhar o valor dependendo da hora da criação da conta e o valor acabaria não atualizando no tempo certo para todos.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso utilizando javascript.
setInterval é o nome da função.

Comment: Mas o setInterval só funcionaria se o usuário estivesse com a aba da página aberta também. O objetivo é pegar o valor negativo do tempo que se passou para dar o dinheiro do usuário na quantidade correta

Comment: javascript e momentJS... no momentJS você consegue contralar horas, daí só usar a biblioteca adaptando a sua necessidade, qualquer dúvida comenta aqui que tento ajudar melhor.

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade Ainda não tinha ouvido falar sobre o momentJS, vou pesquisar sobre ele